# Is there any simple out of box infrastructure to execute action (event) in a main manager thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency

I would like to implement a main (manager) thread what starts multiple worker threads. The worker threads generate events, and calling back to the provided event handler. I would like to execute the event handlers in the main thread (serialized). (just like Control.Invoke executes the action in the thread in which the control was created)

I know this involves a message loop in the main manager thread, and a message queue in which the callbacks are serialized, please do not go into the details explaining this.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, and implement this from scratch. Is there any in .NET out of box, or any light opensource implementation for this? (like concurrent pattern implementations or similar)

Please note: There is no GUI, just N+1 threads.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at the TPL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @quantdev: I looked it, and I thought I knew TPL, maybe I missed something. Could you point within that pretty big page where is exactly the way to marshal a method call to an other thread?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to possible constructs in Task Parallel Library, you can achieve this through [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). Here is a very rough idea but you should be able to refine this. Main thread, after starting worker threads, would wait on `AutoResetEvent`. When a worker thread wants main thread to do something, it can set the `AutoResetEvent` instance and the main thread will continue.

Following is a simple example.

(At class level)

```
const int MaxThreads = 5;
AutoResetEvent[] _waitHandles = new AutoResetEvent[MaxThreads]; // one for each thread
ActionEnum[] _callbackActions = new ActionEnum[MaxThreads]; // one for each thread
object _callbackActionsLock = new object();
```

(Main thread)

```
for (int i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
{
    _waitHandles[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
}

// start 5 worker threads passing each thread its zero-based index...

// Wait loop:
for (int i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
{
    bool result = _waitHandles[i].WaitOne(500);
    if (result)
    {
        PerformAction(i);
    }
}

private void PerformAction(int i)
{
    switch (_actions[i])
    {
        case Actions.CallbackA: ...
            break;
        case Actions.CallbackB: ...
            break;
            ...
    }
}
```

Worker threads can set and the wait handles like this

(worker thread)

```
// ... do some work
lock(_callbackActionsLock) // if no other thread will use this index of _callbackActions then no need for this lock
{
    _callbackActions[currThreadIndex] = Actions.CallbackB;
}
_waitHandles[i].Set();
...
```